# Kamatz with yod in פָּנָיו?

Tags: pronunciation

In the Aaronic blessings, should פָּנָיו be pronounced as PANAIW or PANAW? The yod can't be redundant right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *yod* is a *mater lectionis* and is not pronounced at all.

You can tell that this is the case because there is no vowel mark on the *yod*.

(This rule of thumb does have one exception: the last letter of a word may be printed without a vowel sign, even though it is to be pronounced. In such a case the *schwa* is implied but not printed.)

Comment: Thank you. What if the last letter is a ה‎, without mappiq, and without a vowel sign, does it imply a schwa sound?

Comment: @hewei That's exactly why the mappik sign exists: to disambiguate final hei whose assumed shva may not have been obvious. Every other letter's status at the end of the word can generally be determined clearly from context.

Comment: Why not use aleph or ayin as the mater lectionis? Why yod?

Comment: 1) For vav to to be used as a consonant not vowel, is it usually the case that yod is to be used a the mater lectionis before vav? 2) what will be wrong  the yod is replace by an aleph in this particular example?