Pronouncing "kometz yod vav" (e.g., "אָיו__")
Words like יראָיו and שערָיו, with a kometz vowel followed by yod and vav without any vowel, are pronounced "AHV" [or "AHW"] by everyone I know of - ignoring the yod's Y or EE sound. [There is someone in my family who learned Hebrew later in life and still finds this difficult, tending to end these words AYV.]
I was wondering:

Does everyone pronounce it this way, and has that always been true?
Are there any other examples in Lashon Hakodesh where a letter is completely ignored? I'm not asking about קרי and כתיב, I'm asking about standard spelling of Hebrew words that is not phonetic.
If this is unique, what is going on? Why would we have exactly one non-phonetic structure in Lashon Hakodesh?

Update: @JoelK brought what I think is a very good similar example that I completely missed: segol yod chaf, like שערֶיךָ: shaarehcha, not shaareicha. Again the segol is the only vowel, and the yod seems to be ignored.
This seems to be the upshot of the comments: This sort of thing is more common than I thought.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mater_lectionis

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/124025/

Thank you, @JoelK, this is a duplicate. But I don't understand the reference to mater lectionis, where the whole point here is that the consonant indicates the wrong vowel.

related, another use of י for a different vowel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/115575/759

@DoubleAA Truth is, I see that it would be hard to say, "AYW". So that is a good point really.

@MichoelR how do you know which consonant, when used as a mater lectionis, is meant to indicate which vowel?

@MichoelR It's also interestingly much closer sounding to the singular masucline suffix שְׂעָרוֹ

@JoelK consonant Y vowel EE?

@MichoelR There’s not necessarily a reason a priori that that has to be the case. Consider also the yod after tsere (presumably not originally a diphthong) or after segol.

@JoelK You can see why I didn't think the ones after tsere were  problematic. The one after segol, from DoubleAA's link sounds like no one knows how to say it! But it's an interesting addition.

@MichoelR There’s also the regular case of yod after segol in eg שעריך - that one seems to be clearly left unpronounced. Also, for another possible example of yod as mater lectionary after kamatz, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117899/the-second-yod-in-mechiyael

Also Yirmiyahu 37:13 יראייה

@JoelK I think that one of שעריך etc. is really something I missed: a standard pronunciation where the yod is not doing its job.

I've always wondered how to pronounce words like עבדָיך in targum. It's not a silent yud, is it?
